# Swift AppDelegate or Main throwing an exception on startup but not crashing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I have breakpoints for all thrown exceptions, and for some reason my breakpoint is being hit on startup of my app every single time. But if I just hit the *play* button a few times then it gets passed it and seems to work normally. The only other symptom is that when I hit a simple UIButton on the home screen that kicks off a storyboard segue, the CPU usage jumps up to almost 50% and the app stalls for a good 2-3 seconds before the segue happens. Same thing when I click on a UITextView view. The app kind of stalls for 3 seconds before the keyboard appears. Any ideas on what could be going on?

I also get this error showing up randomly, it doesn't seem to be tied to any user interactions, but also consistently (pretty much everytime I run the app).

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x10bbf9b40> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x10bbf9ef0> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

According to another SO question, it seems like you should rarely get this message and that it get's triggered when trying to open the camera or something. I don't know why I would be getting it consistently every time.

I've also commented out *all* the code in the app with the exception of the storyboard IBOutlets. And I still get the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Does console print out anything?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Create a new single screen project. Does it still happen?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? If you make a fresh "hello world" app, does it run without the issues above?

Comment: Version 7.2, both device and simulator. A fresh new app works without issue. I'm just going to keep deleting things and commenting out code until I can get it to work I guess and hopefully putting everything back together won't be too bad. Version control is a blessing in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one of the issues is that I had included a font but I forgot to include it in the `copy bundle resources` list.

This can be found by going to your apps target > Build Settings > copy bundle resources. That solved the problem of the exception being thrown on startup and the breakpoint being hit.

However, the app still takes like 3 seconds and 50% cpu to hit that button. And I still get the Communications error message. But the delay seems to not be as bad on an actual device, so maybe it's not an issue.